# Marijuana effects on body

Tags: side-effects, lasting-effects-duration, marijuana

I have looked online but can't find a clear answer. If you eat cannabis, what are the negative effects on the body. Most effects I see online are from smoking the cannabis. But not to much about marijuana its self.